# Keycloak: Can not get attributes of a role

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have set an attribute to a role.Go to **Roles**->Edit a role->go to tab Attributes and then add a key and a value.
Then with the below code I try to retrieve the attribute. I manage to retrieve all roles (role.getName() has a value) but the attributes are null. Did I forget to set something to keycloak?

```
  Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://host.docker.internal:8080/auth")
            .realm("test")
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .clientId("testId")
            .authorization(kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getTokenString())
            .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(20).build())
            .build();    
    
  RealmResource realm = keycloak.realm("test");
  realm.roles().list().forEach(role->System.out.println(role.getName() +  " " +role.getAttributes()));
```

Comment: My guess is - your client version and keycloak version are different, check actual json responses from rest api.

Comment: Both of them are 10.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `realm.roles().list(false)` to get all data.

```java
@param briefRepresentation if false, return roles with their attributes
```

Comment: I downgraded to keycloak 8.0.1 and I do not have the option of realm.roles().list(false). I have only option realm.roles().list() and now unfortunately I do not retrieve attributes again. Any suggestion?

Comment: I managed to find a solution. realm.roles().get("Admins").toRepresentation().getAttributes()

Comment: It is good, if you are looking for specific role, but if you are looking for roles having specific argument, you must get them all and filter them out.